# How to remove trailing 0s and offset from Oracle db

Tags: database, oracle, datetime, time, utc

I'm working with an Oracle database (version 12c) containing a `date` column with the dates in the format `YYY-MM-DD H23:Mi:SS`.

All the dates are stored in EST.

I'm converting these dates to UTC so `2021-09-23 09:12:22` would appear as `2021-09-23 14:12:22`.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT my_date,
       FROM_TZ(CAST(my_date AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/New_York') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS my_date_utc
FROM my_table
```

Here is a sample of my results:

```
my_date               my_date_utc
-------------------   -------------------
2018-04-28 21:21:26   2018-04-29 01:21:26.000000 +00:00
2018-12-18 07:42:25   2018-12-18 12:42:25.000000 +00:00
```

How do I remove the ".000000 +00:00" from the results? So the result would appear as:

```
my_date               my_date_utc
-------------------   -------------------
2018-04-28 21:21:26   2018-04-29 01:21:26
2018-12-18 07:42:25   2018-12-18 12:42:25
```

Comment: Do you want to **display** the result without the fractional seconds and time zone information, or do you want to actually change the data type from "timestamp with time zone" to "date"? If it's just how the result is **displayed**, use `to_char` with the desired format model; if you actually need to change the data type, wrap within `cast ( .... as date)`.

Comment: @mathguy I want to display the result without the fractional seconds and time zone. So "2018-04-29 01:21:26.000000 +00:00" would appear as "2018-04-29 01:21:26"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display a timestamp with time zone in whatever (valid) desired format, you need to use `to_char`. Something like this (not tested):

```
SELECT my_date,
       to_char(
         FROM_TZ(CAST(my_date AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/New_York') 
                 AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AS my_date_utc
FROM my_table
```